# How to simulate keystroke in a GUI application programmatically?

Tags: macos, applescript, applications, automator, ui

On Windows I use AutoHotKey, I can create a GUI window that can be "Always On Top", I can create different Tabs that contain buttons with names that will send keystrokes/macros to a particular application or window id.

I need something to do this on Mac, can AppleScript do this or is there another solution?
The AHK GUI is on the left sending keystrokes/macros it can uses regex and cut/copied strings then modify and paste them.
[image]

Comment: Applescript or Automator, but you “tell” applucations to do things...

Comment: [applescript-how-to-identify-buttons-and-press-them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328673/applescript-how-to-identify-buttons-and-press-them?rq=1) also, consider searching the site using the tags [tag:applescript] etc., and read some code. :)